# Swift: CInt to Int conversion?

Tags: casting, integer, type-conversion, swift, nsnumber

What is the most concise way to convert a CInt to an Int (the native integer type) in Swift? Right now I'm using:

```
NSNumber.numberWithInt(myCInt).integerValue
```

Is this the preferred approach?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var c: CInt = 4
var i: Int = Int(c)
```

CInt is a type alias of Int32 which is one of the types Int can take in its init.

Here are the types I've found you can use like that: UInt8, Int8, UInt16, Int16, UInt32, Int32, UInt64, Int64, UInt, Float, Double, Float80

Comment: Simple, thanks! It looks like you can go the other way too: CInt(myInt)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        var myCInt : CInt = 4

        var newNumber : NSNumber = NSNumber(int: myCInt)
```